# var is not defined in angular testing

Tags: javascript, html, angular, testing, undefined

I am tetsing an angular app in protrator and do not understand why this happens.

I have this test:

```html
beforeEach(function() {
  
        browser.get('http://localhost:8080/#/');

...

        //name
        let name = element(by.css("*[id='field_nombre']"));
    
       }
       
        it('Scenario 1', function () {
        name.click();
        ....
```

It says name is not defined.

I do this:

```html
 beforeEach(function() {
      
            browser.get('http://localhost:8080/#/');

    ...

        
           }
           
            it('Scenario 1', function () {
             //name
            let name = element(by.css("*[id='field_nombre']"));
            name.click();
            ....
```

And the test works. Is there any reason why it doesnt recognises teh vars initialisec inside beforeeach??

Comment: They are two different function scopes. You can declere it before the beforeEach function.

Comment: BeforeEach is executed before every it() function and the part of the browser opens everytime when executing an it()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let name;
beforeEach(function() {
  browser.get('http://localhost:8080/#/');
  name = element(by.css("*[id='field_nombre']"));
}      
it('Scenario 1', function () {
  name.click();
}
```

Comment: Apparently this was the reason! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`beforeEach` has its own isolated function scope and `it` has its own functional scope. we can't access variables that are initialized in beforeeach from other function.

initialize the  variable outside the beforeeach function.

```
let name;
beforeEach(function() {

        browser.get('http://localhost:8080/#/'); 

        //name
        ame = element(by.css("*[id='field_nombre']"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let name = element(by.css("*[id='field_nombre']"));
```

name is defined inside `beforeEach()`. So the scope of name will available only inside `beforeEach()`. It can't accessible from outside of the method

Comment: Thanks! This is the reason

Answer (score 0):

Because your `let name =` is in different scope than it's usage.

In JS `let` keyword shrinks scope from function-wide to block-wide:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    // i is visible
}

// i is no longer visible as it's scope is only inside `for`
```